# rmongodb + shiny --> error 15

Tags: r, mongodb, serialization, shiny, rmongodb

I am using a mongodb to save some data for a shiny app. It seems to be working fine except that one `mongo.update` operation doesn't work when I invoke it in my shiny app. The crazy thing is that if I use it manually in R everything works fine.

So I tried all the "error getting" functions in rmongodb and after the attempted update `mongo.get.err` returns "15" if run in the shiny app  but "0" when running it manually. I have only been able to find one list that explains what this error means (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-153) and it seems to mean *overflow*. The mongodb log simply doesn't say anything as far as I can see.

I tried debugging by using `print` with all the parameters fed to `mongo.update` and I am convince it is passing the right data.

So left is to figure out how using shiny + rmongodb can collude to create this problem.

The bson object I am passing contains a 714.6 Kb serialized object. If I remove this from the object the `mongo.update` is successful.
So what exactly could be causing this? Any hints are appreciated. I have been pulling my hair out due to this for two days now...

mongodb version: 2.6.3
rmongodb version 1.6.53
R Under development (unstable) (2014-03-05 r65119)
64 bit linux mint

Answer (score 2):

***Summary of "discussion":***
The boot function saves the whole working environment in the output (presumably for multi-threading purposes). This apparently means that all variables in the environment gets serialized when the object is serialized.
For this reason the object can become very big and rmongodb cannot handle that apparently.

The only solution I could come up with was to remove the offending reference:
`loess_boot$statistic <- NULL`

There is probably no need for that part anyway but I guess it should be possible to do something smarter with the refhook argument to serialize.

I still wonder why mongodb cannot handle writing the object. What should be the size limit?

Comment: to further explain and hint at a solution I will copy here what teh help says:

_GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16MB. There are several commands in rmongodb available to work with gridFS._

Comment: GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16MB. There are several commands in rmongodb available to work with gridFS.

Answer (score 0):

looks very strange. I assume that there are issues with the mongo db connection due to shiny reactive programming.

Do you test for a working connection before executing commands?

```
  if (!mongo.is.connected(mongo)) {
   ...
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for not getting back before.
I do not check at the moment. But as I said it works if I don't include the "big" serialized object. So it cannot really be that since the check would happen before anything is written anyway.

Comment: The plot thickens... If I replace: success <- mongo.update(mongo, ns_sysmodels, criteria, buf) with: `mongo.remove(mongo, ns_sysmodels, criteria = criteria)`
    `success <- mongo.insert(mongo, ns_sysmodels, buf)`
It works when there is no record already present. But if I run it again it fails. The `mongo.remove` is successful. But not the insert.
So then it works every other time now since the `mongo.remove` always removes the record.

Comment: I think I found the problem. `object.size(loess_boot)` returns around 700Kb, where `loess_boot` is the object I want to write (serialized).
If I do `temp = serialize(loess_boot, connection = NULL, ascii = FALSE)` then `object.size(temp)` is about the same when I run it manually. But when used in shiny it will be about 15000Kb or 30000Kb if re-run; at which point it will fail. So the serialized object is not consistent. The deeper cause seem to be that `loess_boot` contains an environment function. If I remove just that part the size of the serialized object remains constant and around 700Kb.

Comment: Btw. `loess_boot` is the output from the boot function in the boot package. Any ideas about how to handle this?

Comment: It seems like boot saves the whole calling environment in the object. So that is the reason for the size difference when called in shiny and called "normally".  This has no bad effects until you serialize, but then you also serialize all the objects in the environment as far as I can guess.
Any idea what to do about that? I cannot simply clear the environment because that clears shiny's environment.

Comment: I tried using `mongo.bson.buffer.append.object` instead of serializing, but that gives the error: `Unhandled R type (3) in mongo.bson.buffer.append`.